# 3rd party es6 library using webpack external

Tags: webpack, external, es6-modules

I have a 3rd party library in es6 in my node_modules, that uses react, mobx, ... which I would like to externalize (to make bundle smaller).
I have now found any article nor tutorial how to achieve this.
One way is to transpile the lib into es5 as webpack library, but I would like to use only that parts I need (via require). Is there a way how to use raw es6 lib which uses externalized dependencies?